# Rails 3.2 Nginx Unicorn always try to load index.html (403) from public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, http-status-code-403

I just setup a Nginx and unicorn server fpr my rails app. Till now all went well. Both servers are starting and i can access them through my URL.
But my problem is that nginx always loads the index.html from the public folder as the start page. If I delete the index.html file then the request results in 403 Forbidden error. When I try other routes then it results in 404 not found error. So I assume that there is no connection between the nginx and unicorn server. Maybe I am wrong. Trying to solve this already for hours but had no success. If someone could help me , would be really nice.

Here are my configurations:

nginx.comfig:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/medinow.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.medinow.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/medinow/current/public;

  location / {
    gzip_static on;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

unicorn.conf.rb:

```
worker_processes 4

APP_PATH = "/var/www/medinow/current"
working_directory APP_PATH # available in 0.94.0+

listen "/tmp/unicorn.medinow.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true


timeout 30

pid APP_PATH + "/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

stderr_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.medinow.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_PATH + "/log/unicorn.medinow.stdout.log"

preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

check_client_connection false

before_fork do |server, worker|

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

   old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
   if old_pid != server.pid
     begin
       sig = (worker.nr + 1) >= server.worker_processes ? :QUIT : :TTOU
       Process.kill(sig, File.read(old_pid).to_i)
     rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
     end
   end

 end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

before_exec do |server|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/var/www/medinow/current/Gemfile"
end
```

I just can't figure out where I did the mistake. Maybe someone of you know where I forgot something.

Comment: Looks like you specify index.html in try_files of nginx config?

Comment: ye but if index.html isn't available shouldn't it load then the \@unicorn block which is the unicorn server? Also if I delete all files from try_files except of @unicorn then I get a "wrong number of parameter" error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i found the solution myself. Here is what i did:

The other location-blocks interfered so it always loaded the public folder. After I deleted this lines :

```
location / {
    gzip_static on;
}

location ^~ /assets/ {
  gzip_static on;
  expires max;
  add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

the nginx server connects to unicorn.